# Use gulp-plumber on sass task

Tags: gulp

Whenever there's an error in my .scss file, my gulp task stops and I have to run `gulp` in the Terminal again. I'm trying to use gulp-plumber to remedy this, but can't work out where to place it in the task.

I'm requiring it like this, at the top of my gulpfile:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
...
```

I'm trying to pipe it into the task like so:

```
gulp.task('pre-process', function(){
  gulp.src('./sass/mnml.scss')
      .pipe(plumber())
      .pipe(watch(function(files) {

        return files.pipe(sass())
          .pipe(prefix())
          .pipe(size({gzip: false, showFiles: true}))
          .pipe(size({gzip: true, showFiles: true}))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
          .pipe(minifyCSS())
          .pipe(rename('mnml.min.css'))
          .pipe(size({gzip: false, showFiles: true}))
          .pipe(size({gzip: true, showFiles: true}))
          .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
          .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
      }));
});
```

But when I run `gulp`, I get this error:

```
stream.js:94
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
Error: /Users/realph/Dropbox/temp/mnml/sass/base:4: error: unbound variable $b-color
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating another stream of files in the *watch callback*, and I don't think it's using the top `plumber` plugin.

To do so, you have to change your *callback* to use it like:

```
 return files
   .pipe(plumber())
   .pipe(sass())
   .pipe(prefix())
   .pipe(size({gzip: false, showFiles: true}))
   .pipe(size({gzip: true, showFiles: true}))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('css'))
   .pipe(minifyCSS())
   .pipe(rename('mnml.min.css'))
   .pipe(size({gzip: false, showFiles: true}))
   .pipe(size({gzip: true, showFiles: true}))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'))
   .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
```

You can also specify the `errLogToConsole` to your *sass* pipe

```
.pipe(sass({ errLogToConsole: true }))
```